# How many clusters for each level-2 predictor in multilevel modelling?

Tags: multilevel-analysis

I'm currently running a multilevel LPM and I'm doubting about how much controls to include in my models. I have 60 clusters, and want to include 8 variables at level-2, 1 in which I'm interested, the others are controls. I have enough observations within each cluster. In other studies, I've seen authors include more level 2 variables with less groups. However, in single level regressions, I learned to follow the rule of thumb of 10-20 observations for each predictor.

As theoretical studies I found only deal with one level 2 predictor, I hope you can help me.

Regards,